# How to test async functions in swift using XCTWaiter and exceptions

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation, xctwaiter

I want to test *asynchronous* functions in Swift, hence as shown below, I created a `XCTestExpectation` and passed it on to an `XCTWaiter`. Now, irrespective if the expectation is fulfilled or not, **I get a test ran successfully always**.

Can you point out what is wrong in the code. I followed exactly a blog which was made for Swift 3, however, I am running Swift 4. Is that the issue?

```
func testAsyncFunction() {
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Some description")
        vc.asyncFunction(5) { (abc: Int) -> Int in
            if (abc != 25) {
                // expectation.fulfill()
            }
            return 0
        }
        _ = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)
    }
```

Comment: It's easier to use XCTestCase's convenience functions: `let asyncCompleted = self.expectation(description: "Some description")` and `self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 2.0)`. Seems like XCTWaiter.wait doesn't just returns result and not fails the test in case of timeout.

Comment: worked as expected, thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`XCTWaiter.wait` returns an `XCTWaiter.Result` which you should be observing.

```
func testAsyncFunction() {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Some description")
    vc.asyncFunction(5) { (abc: Int) -> Int in
        if (abc != 25) {
            // expectation.fulfill()
        }
        return 0
    }

    let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0) // wait and store the result
    XCTAssertEqual(result, .timedOut) // check the result is what you expected
}
```

Comment: to add onto this answer. if the expectation is fulfilled or that's what you expect it to be then your assert should be change to: `XCTAssertEqual(result, .completed)`